# How Can I use parallel command to speed up a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, parallel-processing, scripting

I'm new here at stackoverflow.

I wrote a simple shell script to read numbers from one file and check if it exists in another file. The code works just fine, but it takes a long time to complete because one file has 315,000 lines of random numbers. Is it possible to speed it up with the parallel command. I've never used this command and it is complicated and confusing for me. Any help is appreciated.

I tried this way of using parallel command

```
time parallel ::: checknums.sh
```

It took 21 minutes. No difference in speed time from using

time checknums.sh

Here is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
read a b c <<< $line
echo "Checking for patterns...$a, $b, and $c"
awk -v b1="$a" -v b2="$b" -v b3="$c" '$0~b1 && $0~b2 && $0~b3' list-of-numners.txt

match=$(awk -v b1="$a" -v b2="$b" -v b3="$c" '$0~b1 && $0~b2 && $0~b3' list-of-numners.txt | wc -l)

echo "Found $match games(s) with patterns $a, $b, and $c"
done < my-patterns.txt
```

I appreciate any help or suggestions on speeding up the text processing. Thanks

Comment: Probably the I/O will completely dominate over any benefits from parallelizing the code. If you can split the file into smaller chunks and process each on a separate disk, or a separate node in a cluster, that should speed things up.

Comment: You can better focus on the script. Without the 2 txt files it is hard to see what alternatives can be given, but you might win 50% time by combining the 2 `awk` commands: `awk -v b1="$a" -v b2="$b" -v b3="$c" '$0~b1 && $0~b2 && $0~b3' {n++;print} END { print "Found " n " game(s) with...."}' inputfile`

Comment: You are scanning the second, presumably large, file many times. It might be better to construct a single grep/awk/sed command that finds all the matching strings on one go, if there aren't to many matches to try, then sorts through that presumably much smaller output to identify how many of each individual match.

Comment: If you used `sed`, you could emit a "which match" code, then simply use sort to count the number of occurrences of each "which match"

Comment: Certainly combining the codes makes sense - something line `'s/^.*'"${a}"'.*'"${b}"'.*'"${c}"'.*$/MATCH-'"${m}"'/p'` might work (where a,b,c are your 3 search strings and m is the match code for this match), and then repeat for a number of the input rows to make one sed command